# RabbitMQ not receiving all messages

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a NodeJS script that reads all files in a directory and sends a message to a RabbitMQ queue to process them.

There are 129k files. What I do is basically read all filenames with `fs.readdir`, iterate over the array of filenames and send a message to RabbitMQ. And for some reason, the queue does not store 129k messages, but only 3k.

This is my code:

```
files.forEach((fileName) => {
    dispatchMessage(channel, fileName)
    dispatchedMessagesCount++
})

const dispatchMessage = (channel, targetPath) => {
    try {
        channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(targetPath), {
            persistent: true,
            expiration: 10800000,
        })

        logEvent(`Published %s`, targetPath)
    } catch (error) {
        logEvent(`Error publishing  %s`, targetPath)
    }
}
```

I tried to set a very big TTL -3hours- via the `expiration` attribute with no luck.
I don't see any errors on the console output.

Looked like RabbitMQ had some kind of rate limiting policy for incoming messages, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I just tried pushing 15k messages and the broker stored 14754.
So it's not a problem of the queue worker, it's the broker itself not receiving all messages.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the RabbiMQ log files?

Comment: @raeisi No, I haven't. Good point, don't know how I forgot about the logs. I solved the problem with a temporary solution, but will take a look at logs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I just tried pushing 15k messages and the broker stored 14754. So it's not a problem of the queue worker, it's the broker itself not receiving all messages.

You're not using publisher confirmations, so your application is exiting before all of the messages are sent over the socket.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms

Comment: I added publisher confirmations and really strange, I got 'em all but the broker was still showing a few messages. So what I did was applying a 5 milliseconds timeout in every iteration and voila, RabbitMQ received all 85k messages. Looks like there is some kind of rate limit for incoming messages.

Comment: There is no rate limit, you have a bug in your code (or, less likely, the AMQP javascript library being used) Please share a full example I can clone and run.

Comment: ...and by "full example" I shouldn't have to do anything but run a script or a couple commands. It seems pedantic but many users who ask for assistance expect other people to figure out how to get dependencies installed, set up test data, or run the code. The worst offenders just provide a snippet and expect assistance. This isn't directed at you @FélixDaniel, more of a general rant 